# what do the compiler options mean? and '?'followed by '=-03'

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, hiredis

/redis/deps/hiredis/Makefile

```
    CC:=$(shell sh -c 'type $(CC) >/dev/null 2>/dev/null && echo $(CC) ||      echo gcc')
    OPTIMIZATION?=-O3
    WARNINGS=-Wall -W -Wstrict-prototypes -Wwrite-strings
    DEBUG?= -g -ggdb
```

what do the complier options mean? and '?'followed by '=-03'?

Answer (score 2):

for `OPTIMIZATION?=-O3`

1. If the variable `OPTIMIZATION` has NOT been defined, OPTIMIZATION is valued as -O3;
2. On the other side, if the variable `OPTIMIZATION` has been defined, this statement will be skipped, and `OPTIMIZATION` will keep its previous value

Comment: Maybe clarify that `?=` is a conditional assignment operator in GNU Make.

Answer (score 0):

The [GNU make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) has this text for the `?=` operator

> There is another assignment operator for variables, ‘?=’. This is
>   called a conditional variable assignment operator, because it only has
>   an effect if the variable is not yet defined.

So, this statement

```
OPTIMIZATION?=-O3
```

says that if `OPTIMIZATION` has been defined, ignore it and if not, define it and assign a value `-03`.

The `-03` as compiler flags means compile at optimization level 3.